# the page not found in angular 2 and asp mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

i used angular 2 in asp mvc 5

when i use this code , it work and not have problem .

app.module :

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component :

```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>My First  App</h1>'
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

and in header :

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
<base href="/" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">
<!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
<script src="/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="/systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
  System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
```

this code is work . it show me in view : `My First  App` .

but when i used this code it show me error : [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsvdF.png)

i used this code :

app.module :

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { OtherComponent } from './other/other.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent, OtherComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component :

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { OtherComponent } from './other/other.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<h1>My First  App</h1>
                <other-app></other-app>
`
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

other.component :

```
    import { Component , OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'other-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/other/other.component'
})
export class OtherComponent implements OnInit {
    Constractor() { }
    ngOnInit(){ }
}
```

other.component.html :

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
       {{name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

**whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add .html format in `templateUrl: 'app/other/other.component'`

```
'app/other/other.component.html'
```